# How can I monitor traffic on my home network?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, wireshark

I have admin access to my D-Link DSL G604T router which controls one switch (and 2 computers) and three other computers. I want to monitor traffic on this router to find out who is downloading what / what is lagging the system. I can install a silent program on the other computers if necessary. I have never used and do not have active directory or anything like that set up. Wireshark is too low-level for me.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to void your D-Link warranty and get a third party firmware
http://wiki.openwrt.org/inbox/dsl-g604t

You can stick another computer between the router and internet and load linux and use iptables.

I can't remember the names of monitoring software at the moment, but software to load on each pc also exists.

Once that is on you should have access to iptables and you can log anything

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -J LOG --log-prefix "whatever you want " --log-tcp-options --log-ip-options
```

Obviously, you can add any condition limiting any interface or source, destination, or other conditions.

With OpenWRT might be able to even use QoS.

This can be used to give the computers you want priority access and everyone else get the leftovers.  You can even say everyone gets at least 10kb/s (or whatever) and I get everything else unless I am not using it.  You can also leave some website unlimited and restrict others to a maximum download speed.

Comment: "Wireless it still under development, cant vouch for how well that works currently."

This is a router that needs to be working at full capacity 100% of the time. Although I understand DDWRT/Tomato/etc are very well maintained and comprehensive, I'm not really sure that I can trust this to work based on what's on that page. Furthermore, while examining other firmwares (such as from Routertech) it seems that compatability is not very simple...

Comment: @kandauc Your router is 2008 and 10/100.  You should upgrade to a device with gigabit.  It is 10x the bandwidth internally.  Maybe find a device with good openwrt support at the same time.

Comment: considering I live in an area which gets a maximum of 250-350kbps, I don't think that is neccessary.

Comment: @kandauc from your building to the internet you would be correct.  If any 2 devices inside your building need to communicate with each other for any reason they will be able to take advantage of gigabit.  When I need to edit a 8gb video file on my file server gigabit is a must.  To assist in monitoring traffic what OS do your 5 devices have?

Comment: all of the ones that need to be monitored windows 7

Comment: @kandauc Try http://seriousbit.com/   NetBalancer
If your users download the same files you may benefit from a proxy-cache.